# PHP - Get the Group of a user

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am a beginner with the htaccess use, i searched an answer on google but didn't find something good to me.

I would like to do something easy to understand (so I'm sure there is a proper way to do it) but don't know how to do.

I have those 3 files:

.htaccess

```
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /path/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /path/.htgroups
require group intern
require group extern
require group test
```

.htpasswd

```
user1:xxx
user2:yyy
user3:zzz
```

.htgroups

```
group1:user1 user3
group2:user2
```

And in php i would like to make a test on the group. I will have a lot of user in some groups and i will add and remove some so i don't want to do :

```
if($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == 'user1' || $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == 'user2')
```

but

```
if($group == 'group1')
```

Could you help finding an easy way to get this variable $group ?

Thanks a lot,

Bastien

Comment: Hackers love HTTP Basic authentication, its brute-force friendly.

Comment: I know, I currently use it for none confidential information, I I'll move the md5 authtype, but still thank you for the advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research on php.net, i found a way by matching a pattern in a file (here in .htgoups), so i did this function to get a group of a logged user.

```
function getHtGroup(){
    $AuthGroupFile = file("/path/.htgroups");
    $user = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
    foreach ($AuthGroupFile as $line_num => $line) {
        if(preg_match("/(.*):(.*)$user/", $line, $matches)){
            $group=$matches[1];
            break;
        }
    }
    return $group;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on BastienSander's answer. These two functions will get the htgroup file path from the .htaccess file and get a group of the user.

```
function gethtgroupfilepath() {
  preg_match('/AuthGroupFile .*/i', file_get_contents('.htaccess'), $match);
  $htgroupfilepath = array_pop(preg_split('/AuthGroupFile /i', $match[0]));
  return($htgroupfilepath);
}

function gethtgroup(){
  $AuthGroupFile = file(gethtgroupfilepath());
  $user = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
  foreach ($AuthGroupFile as $line_num => $line) {
    if(preg_match("/(.*):(.*)$user/", $line, $matches)){
      $group=$matches[1];
      break;
    }
  }
  return $group;
}
```